# Required String parameter 'graphName' is not present

Tags: javascript, http

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log("excel download");
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "exportGraphExcel", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/msexcel");
    xhttp.send('graphName=graphakki');
```

It gives 400 status in browser.
If Content-type is changed to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" then request is accepted.

Comment: Is that really a question ? What is it, then ?

Answer (score 1):

The [content type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) in a request header is the content of what you're *sending*. You're not sending an Excel file, you're requesting an excel file.

When you send the `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` content type header, you're telling the server that your parameters must be read in the URL ([this is the standard way](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1)).